# Getting error in generating pdf file in java spring

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am generating a PDF file using java spring arch, JSP, jQuery and Ajax.      PDF file is generated but giving error -file damaged, not correctly decoded. I am facing issue in how to set in PDF cell values from database by entity.

Here is the code

`service implementation` 
In this I have to get data, i.e. student name, class name, marks using SQL. All variables are there in entity, I need to set data in pdf cell using entity, seems I am missing out something here, please correct me

```
 @Override
        public Document getPdfResultDetails(Long financialYearId, Long classId) {

            Document  document =new Document(PageSize.A4);
            try {
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("Student Result Details"));
                document.open();
                document.add(new Paragraph("Student Exam Result Details ") );


                PdfPTable table=new PdfPTable(5);
                table.setWidthPercentage(100.0f);
                table.setWidths(new float[] {3.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f});
                table.setSpacingBefore(10f);
                table.setSpacingAfter(10f);
                float[] colWidth={2f,2f,2f};


                PdfPCell studentNameList=new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Student Name"));
                PdfPCell financialYearList=new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Financial year"));
                PdfPCell marksObtainedList=new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Marks Obtained"));
                PdfPCell resultList=new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Result"));
                PdfPCell classNameList=new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Class Name"));


                table.addCell(studentNameList);
                table.addCell(financialYearList);
                table.addCell(marksObtainedList);
                table.addCell(resultList);
                table.addCell(classNameList);
                List<ResultDeclarationDTO> resultDeclarationDTO=new ArrayList<ResultDeclarationDTO>();
                List<AdmissionResultDetailEntity> pdfList=resultDeclarationRepository.findByFinancialYearIdAndClassId(financialYearId, classId);
                if (pdfList==null)
                 return null;
                for (AdmissionResultDetailEntity admissionResultDetailEntity :  pdfList){
                    ResultDeclarationDTO resultExamDeclarationDTO=new ResultDeclarationDTO();

                    table.addCell(admissionResultDetailEntity.getObtainMarks()+"");

                } 
                document.add(table);
                document.close();
                writer.close();


            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return document;

        }}
```

`controller class` in this we are getting data on the basis of financial year id and class id by spring data Repository in service layer

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadStudentResult", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView downloadStudentResult(HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam(name = "financialYearId", required = false) Long financialYearId,
                @RequestParam(name = "classId", required = false) Long classId) {

      try {
          Document document=resultDeclarationService.getPdfResultDetails(financialYearId, classId);
          response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=StudentResult.pdf");
          response.flushBuffer();

    } 

      catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }


            return new ModelAndView();
        }
    }
```

`JSP file (jQuery is also being used)`

```
<div align="center">
        <h1>Students Result Document</h1>
        <h3><a href="/downloadStudentResult">Download Students Result Document</a></h3>
    </div>
$(document).ready(function(){


    callDataTableFunction();
    callPdfFileFunction();
    });
function callPdfFileFunction(){
    //$('#dataTableDiv').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/downloadStudentResult",
        processdata: true,
        success: function(data)
        {
            createPdfFile(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            showErrorAlert("#showAlert", data);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achive and what error did you get? Your pdf generating method works well. trying to add pdf file to your response or just download to disk? @bkumar

Comment: i am not getting pdfcell name and data  from database

Comment: From what I've understood, you are trying to provide data to fill out the table. I gave a mock data instead of your **pdfList** retrieving from the repository `List<AdmissionResultDetailEntity> pdfList=resultDeclarationRepository.findByFinancialYearIdAndClassId(financialYearId, classId);` and it works well.

Comment: i guess you should focus on fetching data from your source. what is the aim of the defining this **ResultDeclarationDTO** in your for loop. you dont even use  anywhere. apart from that your your code is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161505/discussion-between-bkumar-and-krezus).

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your controller code. You are not writing file in response.

The pdf file may be generated at server but not given in response. I believe **"Student Result Details"** is the name of file created.

In your controller code do something like:

```
File pdfFile = new File(<path to pdf>);

response.setContentType("application/pdf");  
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=StudentResult.pdf");
response.setContentLength((int) pdfFile.length());

FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
int bytes;
while ((bytes = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
    responseOutputStream.write(bytes);
}
```

Hope this help. Enjoy :)

Comment: Dear  sir this code is not working as file output stream and response both needs to be surrounded by try -catch method but it showing   runtime error

Comment: Thanks @bkumar for trying it out, but this is just an idea what needs to be done at that place. I believe you can catch the exceptions at make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [Spring MVC PDF Download](http://javahonk.com/spring-mvc-pdf-download/) to download a pdf file in spring mvc, but one thing to note is set the response `content-type` and `header` before generating the file, otherwise you may get a garblend page as I faced with in this question: [garblend page in spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47764826/spring-mvc-export-excel-failed-sometimes-and-data-displays-garblend-on-the-page).